# How to fix multi column header in Latex

Tags: tables

I am trying to build a table with multicolumn header

but it does not look right

The lines in the multicolumn looked missed up

I tried different ways but this was the best case i got

[image]

and this is my script

```
\begin{table*}[htbp]
    \caption{AutoML platforms used in the healthcare domain research.}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}\textbf{\thead{Dataset\\Format}}&
            \multirow{2}{*}\textbf{\thead{Dataset\\Type}} & \multirow{2}{*}\textbf{\thead{Disease/\\Speciality}} & 
            \multirow{2}{*}\textbf{{Research}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}\textbf{\thead{AutoML}}\\ \cline{5-7} &&&&\textbf{\thead{Commercial}}&   \textbf{\thead{Open Source}}
            & \textbf{\thead{Health Related}}\\
            \hline


            \multirow{9}{*}{Unstructured}&Audio&Hearing Aid&\cite{689}&\textcolor{mygreen}{\checkmark}&\textcolor{red}{\ding{53}}&\textcolor{red}{\ding{53}}\\
            

        \end{tabular}
        \label{table_1}
    \end{center}
\end{table*}
```

what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: i think you would be able to take it forward from the answer below

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by the headers being "messed up?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should extend your code fragment to an MWE, which we can test and which reproduce your problem.
- Since you not provide MWE, it is not clear if use of the `\begin{table*}[htbp]` meaning that you have two column documents and have error in its writing, i.e. it should `\begin{table*}`, or you have one column document and you should write `\begin{table}[htbp]`.
- in code fragment you have many errors in the first table: missed are curly braces around intended cells contents:

  - instead `\multirow{2}{*}\textbf{\thead{Dataset\\Format}}` should eventually be `\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\thead{Dataset\\Format}}}` but more correct is `\multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Dataset\\Format}}` and have in document preamble `\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}`
  - instead of `\multicolumn{3}{|c|}\textbf{\thead{AutoML}}` should  eventually be `\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{\thead{AutoML}}}`, but more correct is `\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\thead{AutoML}}`

An MWE which consider two column document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ multirow, makecell,xcolor}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries} % <---
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[htbp]
    \caption{AutoML platforms used in the healthcare domain research.}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c| c|c| c|c| c|}
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\thead{Dataset\\Format}}}  
    & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\thead{Dataset\\Type}}} 
        & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\thead{Disease/\\Speciality}}}  
            & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Research}} 
                & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{\thead{AutoML}}}    \\  % <---
    \cline{5-7} 
    &&&&  \textbf{\thead{Commercial}}
       & \textbf{\thead{Open Source}}
       & \textbf{\thead{Health Related}}\\
        \hline
\multirow{1}{*}{Unstructured}
    & Audio
    & Hearing Aid
    & \cite{689}
    & \textcolor{teal}{\ding{51}}
    & \textcolor{red}{\ding{53}}
    & \textcolor{red}{\ding{53}}\\
\end{tabular}
        \label{table_1}
    \end{table*}
\end{table}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

As you can see, your table is wider than text width, so you should consider to take some action to make table narrower or text bigger width us of the `geometry` package.

One such possibility to make table narrower is reduce `\tabcolsep`, remove vertical lines and remove cell padding at begin and end table with `@{}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mrc{O{1}m}
    {\multirow{#1}{*}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
    \caption{AutoML platforms used in the healthcare domain research.}
    \label{table_1}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} cc cc cc c  @{}}
    \hline
\mrc[2.4]{\thead{\shortstack{Dataset\\Format}}}
    & \mrc[2.4]{\thead{\shortstack{Dataset\\Type}}}
        & \mrc[2.4]{\thead{\shortstack{Disease/\\Speciality}}}
            & \mrc[2.4]{\thead{Research}}
                & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{AutoML}}    \\  \cline{5-7}
    &
        &
            &
                & \thead{Commercial}
                    & \thead{Open Source}
                        & \thead{Health Related}        \\
        \hline
\multirow{1}{*}{Unstructured}
    & Audio
        & Hearing Aid
            & \cite{689}
                & \textcolor{teal}{\ding{51}}
                    & \textcolor{red}{\ding{53}}
                        & \textcolor{red}{\ding{53}}    \\
\end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{ multirow, makecell,xcolor}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[!h]
        \caption{AutoML platforms used in the healthcare domain research.}
\centering
            \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
                \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
                \hline
                \thead{\shortstack{Dataset\\Format}}
                    &\thead{\shortstack{Dataset\\Type}} 
                        & \thead{\shortstack{Disease/\\Speciality}} 
                            &\thead{Research} 
                                & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{AutoML}}\\ \cline{5-7}
                    &
                        &
                            &
                                &\thead{Commercial}
                                    &\thead{Open Source}
                                        &\thead{Health Related}\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        }
            \label{table_1}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (and in landscape mode).

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htbp]
\caption{AutoML platforms used in the healthcare domain research.}
\centering
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=3pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccccc}[hvlines]
\Block{2-1}<\bfseries>{Dataset\\Format}
    & \Block{2-1}<\bfseries>{Dataset\\Type}
        & \Block{2-1}<\bfseries>{Disease/\\Speciality}  
            & \Block{2-1}<\bfseries>{Research}
                & \Block{1-3}<\bfseries>{AutoML}    \\ 
    &&&& \bfseries Commercial
       & \bfseries Open Source
       & \bfseries Health Related\\
Unstructured
    & Audio
    & Hearing Aid
    & \cite{689}
    & \textcolor{teal}{\ding{51}}
    & \textcolor{red}{\ding{53}}
    & \textcolor{red}{\ding{53}}\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\label{table_1}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix`uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]